# ReactJs detect much changes with onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[1] I created a "data-base"

```
const dataTodo = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Resolver esse erro",
        check: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "DOMINAR React",
        check: true
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Flavio",
        check: false
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "Manuela",
        check: false
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        text: "Gabriel",
        check: false
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        text: "Felipe",
        check: true
    }
]

export default dataTodo
```

[2] I created a simple Todo component

```
import React from "react"

function TodoItem(props){
    return(
        <div>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={props.item.check}
                onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}
            />
            <p>{props.item.text}</p>
        </div>
    )
}


export default TodoItem
```

[3] And a tried to map all the "data base" with the component

```
import React from "react"
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem"
import dataTodo from "./dataTodo"

class Todos extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            todos: dataTodo
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(id){
        console.log(id)
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const updatedTodo = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
                console.log("before", todo.check)
                if (todo.id === id){
                    todo.check = !todo.check
                }
                console.log("after", todo.check)
                return todo
            })
            return{
                todos: updatedTodo
            }
        })
    }
    render(){
        const allTodos = this.state.todos.map(item => <TodoItem key={item.id} 
                item={item}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        )
        return(
            <div>
                {allTodos}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Todos
```

Buuut, when i click in a checkbox nothing happens, so i tried to console.log the events, and is working, but one million times!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvY3F.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxWoT.png

edit: sorry, my first time here

Comment: Please edit your question and include text copies of your relevant code, instead of pictures.

Comment: images are only good for showing UI, never for code. please change and only add relevant code. too much code is overwhelming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set the state like the following code:

```
import React from "react"
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem"
import dataTodo from "./dataTodo"

class Todos extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            todos: dataTodo
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(id){
        const todos = [...this.state.todos]
        const index = todos.findIndex(elem => elem.id === id)
        todos[index].check = !todos[index].check
        this.setState({todos})
    }
    render(){
        const allTodos = this.state.todos.map(item => <TodoItem key={item.id} 
                item={item}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        )
        return(
            <div>
                {allTodos}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Todos
```